# Request for resetting a password from a different controller with fos user bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to create a form for registering new user without defining their password. The idea is to save the new user and then asking to change the password through the reset password procedure from fos user bundle.

I can't figure how I can trigger the procedure for resetting password in my controller.

Here is the submission part of my controller :

```
if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {

        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $tokenGenerator = $this->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');
            $password = substr($tokenGenerator->generateToken(), 0, 8);

            $user->setEnabled(false);
            $user->setPlainPassword($password);

            /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
            $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
            $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);

            $userManager->updatePassword($user);
            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            // Is this isn't supposed to send an email to the newly created user asking to change his password ?
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_REQUEST, $event);

            return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('some_url'));
        }
    }
```

As commented in the code :

Is this isn't supposed to send an email to the newly created user asking to change his password ?

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_REQUEST, $event);
```

Comment: Why not just insert the new user into the database with a temporary random created password en then send the user an email yourself because you might want to send a different text the first time after user registration instead of after a password-reset.

Comment: Sure I could do all the stuff by myself but I will end up sending an email that finally link to the reset password action from fos user. I may be wrong but isn't a better approch to call direcly fos user bundle (with eventually some custom template or overriden controller in others places) and let it handle the work as it has been designed for ?

Comment: No. a registration is never a password-reset in my opinion. But where possible you can still use parts of the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps you i solved it this way

set the new password with usermanager

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$entity->setPlainPassword("123");                    
$userManager->updateUser($entity);
```

Comment: I'm already doing this in the code I provided. This is not what I'm trying to achieve. What I'm trying to do is creating a new user with some sort of a "need reset your password" state. I'm already setting a random password and I though that fos user bundle could provide this "state" and handle the rest of the actions.

Comment: hmn i also dont see any other option than just sending the user the randompassword with a link where the user can login and has a form to change its password using the code above